# Power BI dax function to add number from previous cell in same column

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I have been doing some analysis based on customer orders in excel, now I want to replicate same in power BI.
Having trouble in one "if formula"

In this formula I want to see purchase rate of customer based on how many time they come
Excel formula is
`=if(A3=A2,B2+1,1)`

In power BI I unable to add number from above cell. Please help me regarding this issue.
I am new to Power BI.

Comment: You have a problem here because in Powerbi you work with datasets. Those do not have an order as you have in excel (rows in the sheet). You need to first have add order column like a date or index to your data.

Comment: Okay then which dax formula i can use ? @Aldert

Comment: You need to us Calculate and fileter the previous row out, I can help out but I need to know what is your column dictating the order

Comment: You can add an `Index` column and use that to refer to previous rows. That canl be slow with large datasets.  There are faster methods useful in Power Query. Not sure about DAX.